# Using collectd instead of topbeat in an ELK implementation for monitoring system statistics

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, collectd

In a use case for gathering system statistics(CPU and RAM) of multiple systems via ELK stack, I believe it should be straight forward to use topbeat -> elasticsearch -> Kibana. Is there any reason why one should still go for collectd -> logstash -> elasticsearch -> kibana?

Comment: If all you want is cpu and process load, then topbeat should be fine.  collectd is more of an infrastructure.  They probably expect beats to get there eventually.  See https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Table_of_Plugins

Comment: Thanks @Alain for your response. Yes topbeat should allow collectd style plugins to be more flexible.